# SPException error codes and meanings (refreshing form request digest via SharePoint REST services)

Tags: rest, error-handling, exception-handling, documentation

Where can I find a list of error codes and their meanings for SharePoint exceptions?  I can't find any list of any kind online, just specific cases here and there.

My specific need arises out of the following scenario:

- SharePoint 2013 REST services
- Refresh form request digest

I have discovered that if my form request digest has timed out, I will receive:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "-2130575252, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "value": "The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."
    }
}
```

That's great, I can just look for error code -2130575252, refresh my request digest and try it again, right?  Well, maybe ... I'm left wondering in what other scenario might this error code be used?  What other error codes may indicate a similar situation?  With a little error code documentation I could feel more confident that this is the one and only error that a stale request digest will produce.  Alas, where's the documentation?

Comment: I am getting the same error trying to execute a RESTful CopyTo via Google Advanced Tool ... am pretty sure my url is valid.. I wonder if I need to imput a digest or is that in the context of an app (.aspx)